# Double Decodes for HMAC JWTs using kids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, hmac

We are trying to use ruby-jwt to encode/decode HS256 signed JWTs using  `kid`s to indicate the record in a keystore that represents the key to use, but it seems like we need to do 2 decodes for verification. One decode not using a secret or indicating to ruby-jwt that we want to verify the JWT just so we can scrape the `kid` out of it, then a second decode that passes in the secret that the `kid` represents, and the flag to verify the JWT. It's a minor thing and b64 is cheap, but is doing 2 decodes really the approach that needs to be taken for HMAC JWTs with `kid` in them? Is this a limitation of the library, or a gap in knowledge on how to work with `kids` with HMAC?

## Create JWT with HS256

```
keys = {'31b88f20-8edd-49fe-a839-57b8f681888c' => 'mysecret'}
payload = {user_id: 99, kid: keys.first.first, exp: 5.years.from_now.to_i}
token = JWT.encode(payload, keys.first.second, 'HS256')
```

## Verify JWT

```
# Get the kid from the jwt so we can look up what secret to use to verify it by the kid
decoded_jwt = JWT.decode(token, nil, false)
kid = decoded_jwt[0]['kid']
secret = keys[kid]
# decode the jwt again with the secret, and verify it
decoded_jwt = JWT.decode(token, secret, true)
# => [{"user_id"=>99, "kid"=>"31b88f20-8edd-49fe-a839-57b8f681888c", "exp"=>1865946624}, {"alg"=>"HS256"}]
```

It works but trying to see if there is a better approach. Thanks!

Comment: Libraries usually support the search in a JWKS. ruby-jwt also seems to support this (see [here](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt?tab=readme-ov-file#json-web-key-jwk)).

Comment: Thanks -- its my understanding that JWKS is for asymmetrical algorithms only, as a way to advertise the public keys -- and as HMAC is symmetrical, there are no public keys (https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets)

Comment: [RFC 7518](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-6) states: *"A JSON Web Key (JWK) [JWK] is a JSON data structure that represents a cryptographic key.  These keys can be either asymmetric or symmetric. They can hold both public and private information about the key."* and [RFC7517](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517#appendix-A.3) shows JWK Set with symmetric keys using HMAC.

Comment: I am not aware that JWK Sets are necessarily *only* intended for public keys (in the context of asymmetric encryption). Just try it out for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the double decoding by using JSON Web Key Set (JWKS).

To implement this process using JWKS and HMAC you can do so as follows.

Encoding:

```
require 'jwt'

secret = 'mysecret'
kid = '31b88f20-8edd-49fe-a839-57b8f681888c'
algorithm = 'HS256'

# Used strings for comparison at the end 
# Used Time so it did not rely on Rails
payload = {"user_id" =>  99, "exp" => Time.now.to_i + 10000}

# Encoding pass kid as a header field 
token = JWT.encode(payload, secret, algorithm , kid: kid)
#=> "eyJraWQiOiIzMWI4OGYyMC04ZWRkLTQ5ZmUtYTgzOS01N2I4ZjY4MTg4OGMiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo5OSwiZXhwIjoxNzA4MTE3ODIzfQ.UArtkNyPx0ri08i6D2t7sLtZ_dlqoDczP7r4ZVPtTGM"
```

Export Keys:

Since HMAC is a symmetric key the Key Type (`kty`) needs to be set to 'oct' See [RFC7518 at 6.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-6.1), and the Key Value (`k`) is set to the secret See [RFC7518 at 6.4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-6.4.1)

```
#Create a JWK by importing the Hash
jwk = JWT::JWK.new({ kty: 'oct', k: secret, kid: kid, alg: algorithm  })

# JSON Web Key Set for advertising your signing keys
jwks_hash = JWT::JWK::Set.new(jwk).export
#=> {:keys=>[{:kty=>"oct", :kid=>"31b88f20-8edd-49fe-a839-57b8f681888c", :alg=>"HS256"}]}

# OR export private keys (Not recommended refer to: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517.html#section-9.2)

jwks_hash = JWT::JWK::Set.new(jwk).export(include_private: true)
#=> {:keys=>[{:kty=>"oct", :k=>"mysecret", :kid=>"31b88f20-8edd-49fe-a839-57b8f681888c", :alg=>"HS256"}]}
```

Decoding:

```
# If you did not export the private secret, if you did this step can be skipped
jwks_hash[:keys].each {|k| k.merge!(k: secret)}

# Create a JWKS
jwks = JWT::JWK::Set.new(jwks_hash)

#Decoding
decoded = JWT.decode(token, nil, true, jwks: jwks)
#=> [{"user_id"=>1708119080, "exp"=>1708119627}, {"kid"=>"31b88f20-8edd-49fe-a839-57b8f681888c", "alg"=>"HS256"}]

decoded[0] == payload
#=> true
```